# How to assign value in the callback function?

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with a `callback` function

```
project.prototype.getFolder = function(path){

    this.imagePath;
    var instance = this;

    function getImage(image, callback) {
       var it = function(i){
         codes.....
         //I am sure variable image is not null
                  callback(image);

         codes....
        }
    }

   // function to get the image
   getImage(image, function (img) {
        instance.imagePath = img;
   });

   //it outputs undefined...
   console.log(this.imagePath )

}
```

I want to assign the value to `this.imagePath` inside the `callback` function, but it seems I am getting `undefined` in my case.
I am sure I pass valid `image` variable but I am still getting nothing. Can anyone provide a tip? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might some of those `codes.....` include an asynchronous operation? Because asynchronous operations must wait for the current function stack to resolve before they can resolve, `console.log` is running *before* whatever asynchronous operation is ordered inside of `getImage`.

Comment: console.log(this.validImagePath)... where do you update validImagePath?

Comment: sorry guys, it's a typo. and yes apsillers i have an asynchronous function in my codes...see updates.

Comment: So put `console.log(this.imagePath)` inside your `getImage` callback. Problem solved? If you want to get data out of `getFolder`, pass a callback into that as well

Comment: Is there a call to it() in getImage function()? I don't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code may be asynchronous, hence it takes time for the callback function to run. in this time, while your return value is still not set, you are trying to print out the variable.

Basically even though the code itself is written after the callback, it may run before it.

This is probably your problem, so you should try to access this value only after the callback as been called:

```
   // function to get the image
   getImage(image, function (img) {
        instance.imagePath = img;
        console.log(instance.imagePath);
   });
```

**EDIT:**

In order to get the asynchronous parameter back as a return value for getFolder, you should pass a callback function to getFolder;

**Example:**

```
project.prototype.getFolder = function(path, callback){
    ...
    ...
    if (typeof(callback) == "function"){
        callback(this.imagePath);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
project.getFolder(path,function(imagePath){
    console.log(imagePath);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rodik, the instance.imagePath outputs image path now but if I call the getFolder function from somewhere else, how can I be sure I have value in this.imagePath? Thanks. +1

Comment: Hi Rodik, should i put the typeof(callback) == 'functin' check inside my it = function(i)? I put it inside the beginning of my getFolder function but imagePath still return undefined.

Comment: That would be very good practice. But it's not technically mandatory.
This is to stop your code from crashing if you forget to pass a callback function.

Comment: oh boy, I feel like it's so complex and I don't know where to start now.

Answer (score 0):

You assign imagePath, but try to access to validImagePath. try :

```
 console.log(this.imagePath)
```

And I don't understand why you have  `this.imagePath;` at the beginning. May be you want to write :

```
this.imagePath = path;
```

?

Comment: Ok, so @apsillers suggestion about asynchronous ?