# Javascript Callback function scope issue

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I am having a trouble in

[How to assign value in the callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345895/how-to-assign-value-in-the-callback-function#16346029)

Thanks to Rodik I have some general idea of how to do it. However, I am still not sure how to pass the `img` value to `getImage` `function`...

```
project.prototype.getImagePath = function(){

   codes...

   this.getFolder(path);

   //how do I get the img value inside my getImage function?
}


project.prototype.getFolder = function(path){

this.imagePath;
var instance = this;
var images = ['http://project/path.png', 'http://project2/path.png'];

   function getImage(images, callback) {
        var iterator = function (i) {
           if (i < images.length) {
                     var image = newImage();
                     //..codes to check if image path is valid
                     //if valid, pass image back
                        callback(image);

                    }

                    iterator(++i);
          }
        }
        iterator(0);
    }


   getImage(images, function (img) {
       console.log(img)  //output the img 
       instance.imagePath = img
   });

}
```

Thanks for the help guys~~

Comment: place your main function in project, this way all your prototypes can reference the same data.

Comment: Thanks bfavaretto, it was just a typo

Comment: Forgetting the code for a second, can you go back to basics and explain what you're trying to do?  I'm not making much sense of this so far.  So far, in the call to `getImage()`, as far as I can tell, `image` is not defined.  Is it a global?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I just edit my codes, basically I want to check if the image path is valid, if so, pass the valid image path to getImagePath function.

Comment: @FlyingCat I think you want to use the same callback pattern in `getFolder` as you do in `getImage`

Comment: @apsillers yes i have tried it, but it appears I won't get the valid image path in my getImagePath function right away. I can only use callback to get it which is not accessible when I call getImagePath immediately

Comment: Pass a callback to `getFolder`, just like you pass a callback to `getImage`, and have the body of that callback have the data you need. The data *will not* be available immediately after you call `getFolder`, just as image information is not immediately available after you call `getImage` -- that's why you use a callback. You say you tried it -- do you mean you can't figure out when to fire the callback passed into `getFolder`?

Comment: I have tried it but I was hoping to get the valid image path right after I call getFolder function, using callback can't get the valid image path immediately. I was hoping there is a way to solve this. I guess it's a dead end here

Comment: I'm still pretty unclear on your entire plan.  But if this involves making an AJAX call to a server (or any other asynchronous call), the result is not going to be available when your function returns.  That's simply not how asynchronous programming works.